# (Scala) Implicit Parameters Menu Item in IntelliJ IDEA. How to use it ? What is it good for?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, implicit

There is an implicit parameter menu item in IntelliJ as shown below.

What is it good for ?

How can I use it ?

I tried to press SHIFT-COMMAND-P on parts of the code where implicits are used and nothing happened.

[image]

Comment: You're highlighting the wrong link in your picture

Comment: I noticed it, Great :)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this feature!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using **Intellij 13.1**:

I didn't notice this feature before (thanks :)), but I've just tested it and I can confirm that **Implicit Parameters** reveals the implicit parameters used in a method call while the cursor is placed onto it.

[image]

In my sample, I put the cursor on the outermost wrapping method call, my `Ok` call, and it shows it needs (and uses) an implicit parameter: a `Writeable[JSValue]`.

Also, when the cursor is placed on a nested method call, like in the following `Json.json` call,  a quick use of **Implicit parameters** feature makes IntelliJ suggest you which method to scan for implicit calls up to the outermost wrapping method (`Ok` in this case):

[image]